# How can I look at the SQL query really used by myBatis?

Tags: java, sql, xml, oracle, mybatis

The query, created by myBatis, falls with the cause ORA-00933, "SQL command not properly ended".

All advice that I found on the net, says that there is some error in the SQL syntax. On the other hand, if I make the SQL by hand, Oracle SQL developer takes it as a correct one.

Obviously, I am making it by hand differently that myBatis does. And I need to check it. **But how can I check the SQL query really sent by myBatis to the DB?**

The MyBatis version used: 3.0

---

<sub>I am interested much more in the possibility to look for problems myself than to look for help with every problem. But some people here think that the question must contain the code, so here it is. (mapper.xml)</sub>

```
<sql id="pracovisteSql">
    /* pozor, pracuje pouze do max 3 vrstev v cis_pracovist */
    cis_pracoviste A
        join cis_pracoviste B
            on (A.stupen_rizeni in (0,1) and B.kod_nadrizeneho = A.kod_pracoviste) or
                (A.stupen_rizeni = 2 and A.kod_pracoviste = B.kod_pracoviste)
        join cis_pracoviste C
            on (B.stupen_rizeni = 1 and C.kod_nadrizeneho = B.kod_pracoviste) or
                (B.stupen_rizeni = 2 and C.kod_pracoviste = B.kod_pracoviste)
</sql>
<sql id="organizaceSql">
    WITH organizace
    AS (
        SELECT a.kod_pracoviste as AKP, a.nazev as ANZ, a.stupen_rizeni as AST, a.kod_nadrizeneho as ANR,
                b.kod_pracoviste as BKP, b.nazev as BNZ, b.stupen_rizeni as BST, b.kod_nadrizeneho as BNR,
                c.kod_pracoviste as CKP, c.nazev as CNZ, c.stupen_rizeni as CST, c.kod_nadrizeneho as CNR
            from
            <include refid="pracovisteSql"/>
    )
</sql>
<sql id="zahajeniOdDo">
    (r01.dat_zahajeni between to_date(#{mesicRokOd}, 'MMYYYY') and to_date(#{mesicRokDo, 'MMYYYY'))
</sql>
<select id="getReportSR02Sql1"
        parameterType="amcssz.spr.srv.main.dto.reports.ReportSR02QueryDTO"
        resultType="amcssz.spr.srv.main.dto.reports.ReportSR02Sql1DTO">
    <include refid="organizaceSql"/>
    SELECT Count(Distinct (r01.id_r01_rizeni)) as pocetVRSP     
        From organizace
            Left join r01_rizeni r01
                on organizace.ckp = r01.kod_pracoviste and
                    r01.je_stornovano = 0 and
                    <include refid="zahajeniOdDo"/> and
                    r01.kod_skup_rizeni = 'VRSP'                  /* r01.kod_rizeni in ('VRSPUC', 'VRSPSR', 'VRSPPE', 'VRSPJI') */
            Join r02_stavrizeni r02
                on R01.ID_R01_RIZENI = R02.ID_R01_RIZENI and      /* Změna 17.1.2020 */
                R02.JE_AKTUALNI = '1' and
                R02.KOD_STAV_RIZENI != 'STR'
            Join r08_ukon r08
                on R01.ID_R01_RIZENI = R08.ID_R01_RIZENI and      /* Změna 17.1.2020 */
                R08.KOD_UKON IN ('1','14','23','32') and          
                R08.JE_STORNOVAN = '0'
            Join d02_obalka d02
                on R08.ID_R08_UKON = D02.ID_R08_UKON and          
                d02.dat_doruceni   IS NOT NULL                    
        Where organizace.AKP = #{kodPracoviste} and
            r01.kod_skup_rizeni is Not Null
        Group by r01.kod_skup_rizeni
        Order by 1;
</select>
```

Comment: The LEFT JOIN r01 returns regular INNER JOIN result, thanks to the r01 condition in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for optimization, but alas, it is not about the problem I am interested in...

Comment: That's not what you are asking about but may be helpful with this particular issue: expression `to_date(#{mesicRokDo, 'MMYYYY')` lacks a closing `}` bracket.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Thank you. Surely, you have located the problem of the cited SQL.  But the main problem is the automation of the search for the problem position. Mybatis only names the error but does not position it. God, I would never use it at my will.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your log4j level to show the mybatis logging like `log4j.logger.org.mybatis.example=DEBUG`

Full documentation will be found [here](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use intellij idea, try to add a plugin [mybatis-log-plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10065-mybatis-log-plugin).The executed SQL will be output in the console